# Python float() giving incorrect values

Tags: python, python-2.7, casting, floating-point, precision

When I enter float(1)/(2^7) in the Python console it outputs 0.2. But it is actually 0.0078125.

Could anyone please tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `^` is the XOR operator. If you want to raise 2 to the power of 7, you must use `2 ** 7`.

Comment: try `help('^')` and `help('**')` in Python REPL

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use the `**` operator instead of `^`. `**` is the power operator in python, `^` is the Binary XOR operator.

`float(1)/(2**7)` yields the correct `0.0078125`.